# Primary Key in AspNetUsers above certain value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have requirement in my current app to have primary key for every new `ApplicationUser` to be above certain value, as it does not collide with data I load from CSV file. Web user should have `Id` above Max ID from file. So user that was in base data does not overlap with Web user.

I've implemented integer Primary Keys using [ASP.NET documentation article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity).

How to modify `ApplicationUser` class so that requirement could be meet?